# django not displaying error_messages in forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i am new to django and i have this form i am working on i have tried everything possible i cant seem to display the form error messages. i have tried using a def clean method nothing happens when i try to submit an empty form..i have tired switing to using FormView i have also tried using function view i have tried using a for loop and adding {{ form.non_field_errors }} in my template nothing pops up.

my app/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField( label='Your Name', min_length=2, max_length=25, required=True, error_messages ={'required':'Please tell Oluwafemi your name'})
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email', required=True, error_messages={'invalid':'Please fill in a valid email'})
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Subject', min_length=4, max_length=100, required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Write Oluwafemi a Message'}), error_messages ={'required':'Please write something for Oluwafemi'})
```

my app/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
class ProfilePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'femi_profile.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = 'femiir'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            # Send the email
            send_mail(
                f"{subject} - message from {name} ", # message subject
                message, # Message Body
                email, # Sender's mail (From mail)
                ['d4rahl@gmail.com'], # Reciever's mail(To mail)
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect('femiir')


        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

snippet of my html template

```
<div class="col-lg-7 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.subject|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Send Message</button></div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

please what i my doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Did you try looping through form.errors in template?

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          {{ error }}  
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i just did but it is not displaying anything

Comment: Also try to check if form is valid or not and also I m not seeing any form.save() method so the form will not be saved in the dB. Please apply debugger and see if it is entering into form.is_valid() and if not check to see the form in the debugger. Also form does not have action URL in the template

Comment: this seems like a lot i am new to all this... but i am not using a database this is a contact me form on a portfolio project that just sends mail..where should i add the form.save() method and i dont know how to use a debugger and what is action URL

Comment: Try this ```{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden_field.errors }}
    {{ hidden_field }}
  {% endfor %}``` Does this help? Otherwise you can go through this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html This is much easier and gives a better understanding

Comment: I honestly don't know you from anywhere but i want to appreciate may the Lord who created heaven and the earth continue to bless you, May you soar high, far beyond how you can imagine God will lift you high and bless your life...Thank you so much

Comment: can i ask you for a personal help,? still on the forms...or should i ask another question and refer you to answer?

Comment: If it's not related to this particular one, you should surely ask another one. This will also help other people who may face the similar issue.

Comment: let me hint a bit because it is somehow related 
1) everything is working but first of i cant put it in a div simpleisbetterthancomplex used a for loop all efforts to do render it line by line is not working 


2) secondly my forms reload everytime submitting an empty form will reload and return errors instead of staying on the same page

3)when typing the validation is not working on the fly

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering fields manually you would have to use error tags.

`{{ form.name_of_field.errors }}`

```
        <form method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
          
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.name.errors}}

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.email.errors}}

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.subject|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.subject.errors}}

            {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.message.errors}}

          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: i will try this and give you feedback

Comment: i just tried this and my form only circles the fields red when i try to submit the empty form

Comment: Check your ContactForm, you have set the fields to required=True. Thus, you cannot submit an empty form. if the fields are turning red then that implies that errors are working fine. If you want users to submit an empty form then set required=False

Comment: you have any idea why field errors are not working. It doesn't write the error message below or above the field

Comment: i want it to display something like ** . enter a valid email** when someone fails to write an email or omits it